# Repeat KendoUI Datepicker control due to Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using ASP MVC partial view to create two same partial view in my page

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PVReportingModule");}
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PVReportingModule");}
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have need a KendoUI Datepicker in my PVReportingModule partial view, how do I create and name it? Below is the code in my PVReportingModule partial view

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("xXxX")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the id as parameter:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PVReportingModule", new ViewDataDictionary { { "datePickerId", "picker1" } });}
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PVReportingModule", new ViewDataDictionary { { "datePickerId", "picker2" } });}
    </div>
</div>
```

and then inside the partial use this parameter:

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name(ViewBag.datePickerId)
```